# Angular routing: when navigating to a child route from parent route guard the parent route guard is triggered in infinite loop

Tags: angular, angular-router

Let's assume that we have a web site with profiles of many users. Site is available only for authenticated users. I want to be able to enter empty URL and then after authentication I will be forwarded to my profile. And I want to be able to directly enter another user's profile URL and then after authentication I will be forwarded to his profile.

Routing:

```
{
   path: '',
   canActivate: AuthGuard,
   children: {
     path: ':userId',
     component: UserProfileComponent
   }
}
```

Guard:

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const isLoggedIn: boolean = await this.authService.checkLogin();
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.authService.login();
      return false;
    }
    if (state.url === '/') {
      const loggedInUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
      return this.router.createUrlTree([loggedInUser.id]);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is when I enter an empty URL then AuthGuard is triggered twice and I need to have this check

```
if (state.url === '/') ...
```

to avoid infinite loop.

How to implement it in the way that

```
this.authService.checkLogin()
```

will be called only once?

Comment: move `canActivate` to you child path and remove it from your parent and try.

Comment: @JsNgian if I move ```canActivate``` to the child then I will not be automatically redirected to my profile URL when I enter an empty URL.

Comment: `{ path: '', redirectTo: ':userId', pathMatch: 'full' }` add this to child route and try.

Comment: @JsNgian ':userId' is a dynamic (not static) value. I get 'userId' from authService.

Comment: Yes that's right, But how are you loading :userId without redirect? 
When ever you have an empty path and a child route, you should have component also in that. Without component how are you loading it. Where is your router outlet?

Comment: @JsNgian if I enter an empty URL then my userId is taken from authService in the Guard itself and then the Guard redirects to the child route with my userId as a path parameter. Parent route can be componentless if it has children. <router-outlet> is in the root 'App' component which Angular bootstraps.

Comment: Please [refer here](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/nested-routes/). Hope this helps resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question it seems like using 'good old' setTimeout works here. It forces redirect to happen after 'NavigationEnd' event happens. But is it a good approach at all?

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  async canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean | UrlTree> {
    const isLoggedIn: boolean = await this.authService.checkLogin();
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      this.authService.login();
      return false;
    }
    if (state.url === '/') {
      const loggedInUser = this.authService.getCurrentUser();
      setTimeout(() => this.router.navigate([loggedInUser.id]), 0);
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```